# Rank and number of zero eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there any relation between the rank and the number of zero eigenvalues?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please let us know about your attempts in trying to solve this problem when asking a question. You should also provide information on the context and why you are interested in this.

Comment: You can refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem